# ASP.NET Forms Authentication - JavaScript errors on Login page (when anonymous users visit)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication

On my Login page only I am getting 18 JavaScript errors and the main one seems to be: 'ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.' I have a feeling it has to do with security since I just recently added Forms Authentication to the site. If I login all errors go away.

It seems like sys is undefined when this line tries to run  :

```
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');
```

I have the following in my Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".FormsAuthCookie" loginUrl="Security/Login" protection="All" timeout="120" cookieless="AutoDetect" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

THE MAIN PROBLEM after adding deny users="?":
ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework is failing to load on my Login.aspx page when an anonymous user visits the site.

UPDATE:::
This really doesn't make much sense but after adding EnableCdn="true" to my script manager I do not get any errors when an anonymous user visits the login page.... It just seems like it is a hack for whatever my actual problem is since this is a clean .net webforms project.

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnableCdn="True">
```

Comment: What are the actual Javascript errors?

Comment: I updated with a few things... Not sure if the js error is what matters. When I remove deny users=? the Login page loads all scripts/references with no problem. When I add the auth back it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the authentication is blocking access to the javascript library. if you view the network tab in chrome do you get any errors loading the js files? if so I would say add an exception to the directory in your config file.

Something like:

```
<location path="js">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

I think the reason CDN works is because the files are being loaded from a CDN as oppose to your app so there is no authentication needed for the CDN server.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted answer above here is the `web.config` configuration needed if you are working with the **Visual Studio 2015 ASP.NET 4.5 WebForms Application** project template:

```
<location path="bundles">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

The `bundles` folder does not physically exist but is the **virtual path** for the bundled scripts. See `App_Start\BundleConfig.cs` for more information.

Please note that allowing access to `ScriptResource.axd` and/or `WebResource.axd` in `web.config` as suggested over and over again in so many other threads just **will not work** with the bundling setup of the Visual Studio 2015 ASP.NET **4.5** **WebForms** Application project template.