# Jquery Datatable Ajax GET call not hitting WebMethod but getting parser Error in IE11

Tags: jquery, datatables, asp.net-ajax, webmethod

I am using Jquery Datatables  that makes ajax GET call to webmethod from aspx code behind file .     My code works fine on Firefox,and the call reaches my webmethod perfectly fine , but when it comes IE11 ,I am getting parser error.

[Here is  my .aspx file](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=UeV6XY45) ,
and [here is my code behind file](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=QJr6rmcc)  for the same .

While debugging ,I am getting some errors,[here is the parser](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=kXY9bktZ) error message and the response .

The above mentioned ajax call worked fine(on both IE and Firefox) when I created this on a fresh new website project with VS2015 .
Now I wanted to incorporate the same code into my existing larger website project which is actually developed long ago ,but we migrated to VS2015 .But when I copied the same code into my official website project ,its throwing errors with IE11 ,but still works well with Firefox.While using IE11 ,my ajax GET call is failing and it is not hitting my webmethod .

Error message

> SyntaxError: Invalid character
>      at parseJSON (http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4:4377)

I pasted the full error message [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=kXY9bktZ) .

Can anyone help me resolve this error ?

I tried adding verb GET (as pasted below)entry into my web.config as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288796/asp-net-ajax-client-side-framework-failed-to-load-when-put-the-scriptmanager-on) ,but no luck

```html
<add verb="GET" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="Microsoft.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler" validate="false" />
```

Comment: Added links to my code pasted in pastebin