# AjaxControlToolKit is not working in any of the element of website

Tags: c#, asp.net

A very weirdproblem in my asp.net website. There are UpdatePanel, UpdateProgress & ModalpopupExtender in my page. All were working fine. Suddenly all of them stopped working. e.g. ModalPopupExtender not showing popup. UpdatePanel reloads entire page, UpdateProgress not showing. All this were working but suddenly stopped.

In my Bin folder I have deleted all files & added again & Rebuilded projects but still didn't worked..

UpdatePanel & UpdateProgress

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div class="modal2">
                <div class="center">
                    <img alt="Loading..." src="images/common/loader.gif" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>
           'content here
       </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

ModalPopupExender

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="quteRequest" runat="server" CssClass="quote-request" ClientIDMode="Static">Request A Quote</asp:HyperLink>

<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpInquiry" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="inquiry-form-container" PopupControlID="inquiryInner" TargetControlID="quteRequest" CancelControlID="closeEditPost"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="inquiryInner" runat="server" CssClass="inquiry-form-inner" style="display:none">
<asp:HyperLink ID="closeEditPost" CssClass="cross-close" runat="server" style="margin-right:10px"></asp:HyperLink>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Is your browser version recently updated? Please try in different browser. And check if there are any Javascript error in browser console log .

Comment: @Prasanjit Thing is I checked the version which I downloaded & that is working fine. It was working in my website as well but suddenly stopped working.

Comment: @stuartd in my browser console I can see this error ''Uncaught Error: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load."

Comment: @Prasanjit in my browser console I can see this error ''Uncaught Error: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load."

Comment: There coluld be multiple reasons for this error  like .Net Framework version and browser version.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288796/asp-net-ajax-client-side-framework-failed-to-load-when-put-the-scriptmanager-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableCdn="true">
```

this solved my problem.. For more please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288796/asp-net-ajax-client-side-framework-failed-to-load-when-put-the-scriptmanager-on)