# Asp.net web form based website shows error - ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms

While checking website today which is developed using asp.net webform(.net 4.0) around 2014 showed design breaks after checking I noticed that there are some error in the console.

Not sure why this error suddenly started to show today, could it be due to bad ajax file or some sort of corruption as I'm getting similar error for other .net webform based website.

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://websiteXXX.com/WebResource.axd?d=5SzwYej-C6IKc2XpxIGxEfPBnEcnsf2ijNMwKQeX0lSjJNG1CITL_ccEdAhc9xkOkMH3UNhq3VffnlhP9ceQuCBQZ9A1&t=636284228160000000”.
en:45
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://websiteXXX.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=4703T7Y5WSJ6SFEORAs7TLPAUPSpREhARReV6nsNETm9tVLK2Dq8N6ACQJUEAS0DjutzONcr1hFIEIGSRb02Yzds6unaWYk0Ohm9J61iBoLLmCxrkhQjFyR9b-51N8NNgBUA6lvTG8lyESVXUaiyCKNUsfk1&t=2cc21b5c”.
en:48
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://websiteXXX.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=jD7G3ZzWS30OfGr1-nzBoUxKyXtcbfuUYnNKkjOZGxCnO6ofUqWV9Q6P3l0YDW3yvm8AHovCtFaRp9vVotwwbkptsVJrDUmLsVcCdzRHnCEQZpi4BhgxAcn5_BzyhsFgxPEfwQ2&t=3a1336b1”.
en:49
Error: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.
en:52:40
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://websiteXXX.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=6GIfwW5NIk8YVdQUBoUSdw8_teFCLpaGZuXT9BltuBtMBUEgJauIENwvz-5lAHOHs7roSmFphXJzKtPwXs4IBi2qKo5Xu9asohZ7zQFIgLxsrV1UVTo2TGF-G5tW5spyJFcooTIB3CmNkKv4pPodTZKjAOM1&t=3a1336b1”.
en:56
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://websiteXXX.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=SVRd3p5sxqLRkNZvsASl_qHKNd_EsD7Em0z1kZZKsUc9VUS88b1ehlatIc09u_RZYKinP0KkpUsEIRoWZWC4V4wZCDW1PNIlcAGeQTMCunY5ABoS93xJu4W1URri3RraR6VbuQ2&t=3a1336b1”.
en:57
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://websiteXXX.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=liPBEJshRG6BfJiUI6H1bjejmsntTHSESj5435XDpzn7jyE3zjP5P8pDyWXQPYKGqJyDYemNYEDpOj7eaHhE_TOQimWjTafCcDEPT_-IzPUk98xa9g47-DPKVpM2PbSRDoVVXAjcFdErIMr9oPvCHUd3at41&t=3a1336b1”.
en:58
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://websiteXXX.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=so2-S6sCEWinHjunb1xKM3mqGuiQVUn2N01XLzPdqPR0Zn1x5urYVyz4vejCesXD7qdgPibO0HVa6T7ln_xJ-vgIuDjZGn77Bw51LNHPxM3LNNJvIsdIfVX7H_lY2o1Ld987I-fmlCUDFR6iEiv3_mEJAWs1&t=3a1336b1”.
en:59
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://websiteXXX.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=b5bmOM9G88P7EQM94ZrgSDUiVqbpJb90fw5Reep6EoPFByepzn_cWrrvCdRW-fdsjjAeoMp-XZC7F2KEh5i_u_4bCbS9-3byqjW8IOkiQl1mQEBCJmwnEK2DELKgsAaNlpuNlvx6h4CydmlBmkIf8hdTQkA1&t=3a1336b1”.
en:60
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://websiteXXX.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=5jy8bTvROjYGk4_2ZP4NEWwvKIpI0oldPhL_Eh6m3GrT6ekBrVTo7-GUSxIX6AD6PC5zSqLy8CN6EuZuPiWdFvsSCam2ki-hwabZoFuSQOLcYwuLOIy_SE7zEe0ytt-m15CycOfApMHv9-RV3sqIMlLd8Xg1&t=3a1336b1”.
en:61
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://websiteXXX.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=rmhvV2xwmzqQwS31J44KQbyMR_zRMpUsEAzR2k4zbzQCgANnXCYEh58kTigCaSZ8LT8wrEnzng7fUI8tLzuVwJOyZbmRHqUZZbHk_03U5BHmWNQMhYAEwyVCaAZIeNDVzQIsHHmQ44Soi71NtaKVf6__bFwTaskur12ttbkfE20oCBud0&t=3a1336b1”.
en:62
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://websiteXXX.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=ZNlBs49UYPsWsh1g9g1-3JSj-0tbIQUGbXQP2qwLK1NKGoBKleisjmI-ljano_dkMzL9cyZcEtPSV3Nhres0GcJJTZaM8XQsJWyno5JUrGS0HJsVtsAzlWneSl0XJZp9rdG8zz1palq3F8_Wsj67W1KiUyc1&t=3a1336b1”.
en:63
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://websiteXXX.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=bdIISdk0xOnOOnKm5Lg0V3RHL-LtjxpWdqYP2FQFT3I__XsATZOwY_tamhbv9vEnFGuUjIauXgv27hfO3XcF2nXfkzyXjVKY6ouAzcNC7Z9yIKfO5PWbQ8i8CFLxEMO43TCl_VIh8mFv9pYZllMnJC96TLE1&t=3a1336b1”.
en:64
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://websiteXXX.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=QZwq1tBmc9srltGXrElP8CgnXBmRsy0QkmV1k7sc16SDweMp3N1RcU7MwtqawWy5tvyiJNg2cDqZ7ijTi1VcWgr8BMTibHYR0uI2ssS0O_OV2FQkh3B6L8557KiFL2aZ8yzJp8IiyCHYmP2rHlthqZ_TsPZKRjCFhDHdWWZVB5BobQMc0&t=3a1336b1”.
en:65
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://websiteXXX.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=m_5nYCrZRv0cBHzoHwFw88IyLI68CfWpjJ_WshaxE3-h39TmNXR9dsYGPJsSAjbXCTy7rqIMgCBJ9asmKjDYA3CZoGMYu0umX80AkS1hxXw23cepeBSLvq0lHlmaWiGP3w5CM6SU_XFJSdOyHG4-H05h3lA1&t=3a1336b1”.
en:66
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://websiteXXX.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=t3aTCyZK7M6vzByezVVz_Cs0icKbhxAXxjsT9TQHsWLpMN-bibYGdivH_AqRtO6GZVutz7zUpsy2Aj14_YTFjxra307vqvp5wFDQSEOPF-jF7-lJ7lKtiEQZ_XnrdxT2ws9xXL7Z2L51cQzRqIVWPJ7SMsA1&t=3a1336b1”.
en:67
ReferenceError: Sys is not defined
[Learn More]
en:75:1
ReferenceError: Sys is not defined
[Learn More]
en:1131:1
ReferenceError: Sys is not defined
[Learn More]
en:1134:1
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.
```

For even single .net based website I'm getting below error

```
WebResource.axd?d=pynGkmcFUV13He1Qd6_TZG4nAkbmoskOtxxp5ySS-SKn9PX36JMmpseXOU7BCTEiPJsUpsbpzfd66G07Bi3ozQ2&t=6362842281600
```

Worth mentioning that this error only happens on production server not the local server since this morning.

Comment: Almost definitely an asp.net ajax issue, a missing dll maybe for ajaxcontroltoolkit? Did you check the Learn More link? (could be too generic but maybe not.) I would start by googling `ReferenceError: Sys is not defined.` [One link.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2007/04/09/ajax-fun-with-the-dreaded-sys-is-undefined-error/) And the last error I think is from bootstrap or jquery, I see that all the time.

Comment: Issue is with all the .net webform based website, it it just started showing from today, it breaks validation as ajax part is not working i looked at example & solution but nothing seems to be working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288796/asp-net-ajax-client-side-framework-failed-to-load-when-put-the-scriptmanager-on

Comment: On local it works fine it is just the dedicated server we have this issue since today

Comment: I understand. Compare local dlls with server. Maybe something got deleted? Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours resolving this issue it came to our knowledge that there was nothing wrong with the server it was local firewall which was blocking following files

```
http://website.com/WebResource.axd?d=5SzwYej-C6IKc2XpxIGxEfPBnEcnsf2ijNMwKQeX0lSjJNG1CITL_ccEdAhc9xkOkMH3UNhq3VffnlhP9ceQuCBQZ9A1&t=636284228160000000

http://website.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=jD7G3ZzWS30OfGr1-nzBoUxKyXtcbfuUYnNKkjOZGxCnO6ofUqWV9Q6P3l0YDW3yvm8AHovCtFaRp9vVotwwbkptsVJrDUmLsVcCdzRHnCEQZpi4BhgxAcn5_BzyhsFgxPEfwQ2&t=3a1336b1
```