# Error: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load after some updates on host

Tags: c#, asp.net, host, .net-4.7.1

I have a web site in windows host = https://blobloblo/WebForm5.aspx
When run that link on FireFox developer & take a look at Console logs, 
I will see this error :

> Error: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to

Because of this error many parts of this web site do n't work correctly.
Yesterdays every thing was ok.
But today they closed the host for some hours & did some updates such as plesk's update.
After running the host again this error appeared.
What should i tell them to fix this problem?

---

**WebForm5 ASPX :**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm5.aspx.cs" Inherits="Virtual_Visa_Cards.WebForm5" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Height="26px" OnClick="Button1_Click" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**WebForm5 C# :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Virtual_Visa_Cards
{
    public partial class WebForm5 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = "This is Ajax Call = CallBack";
        }
    }
}
```

---

Related Topic :
[ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load. when put the ScriptManager on a blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288796/asp-net-ajax-client-side-framework-failed-to-load-when-put-the-scriptmanager-on)
I test all answers in the topic upper WITH NO RESULT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plesk i went to `Web Application Firewall` & put  Web application firewall mode to **off**.

[image: Web application firewall mode = off]

I worked one day to solve this issue.